# Watchdog generates duplicated FileModifiedEvent inside Spyder IDE

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, watchdog, python-watchdog

When I run the following script inside Spyder IDE, watchdog fires two `FileModifiedEvent`, instead of one, whenever a file inside the monitored folder is modified. It doesn't matter if the script is run through iPython or inside a regular console. The problem doesn't occur when the script is executed from a command prompt, thus the problem must be related to Spyder.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

monitored_folder = 'D:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\test'

class FolderMonitor(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print(event)

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(FolderMonitor(), monitored_folder)    
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        import time
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

Inside spyder, the output is:

```
<FileModifiedEvent: src_path='D:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\test\\test.txt'>
<FileModifiedEvent: src_path='D:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\test\\test.txt'>
```

Through a command prompt, the output is:

```
<FileModifiedEvent: src_path='D:\\Users\\camposb\\Desktop\\test\\test.txt'>
```

The code is being executed in Windows 7 with Python 3.5.1 and Spyder 2.3.8.

Comment: I tried to replicate the scenario, but it worked properly with Spyder 3.2.6